# Loop Object Values and Check if they Exist in a Different Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to pass a string with or without pipe separated role names, and see if any of those names exist within an existing javascript array.

Using `.includes` works great if it's a single name, but when I have a piped set of names my function won't return true even if any of the names exist in the array.

```
is(roleName) {
    let roles = roleName.split('|')

    return roles.forEach(role => {
        return this.$page.auth.user.roles.includes(role) 
    })
}
```

This is a mixin method for Vue btw.

Thanks

Comment: `forEach()` returns `undefined`, use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: it sounds like what you need is ``return roles.every(role => {,,,})``  or `return roles.some(role => {,,,})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) if you'd like to check if all roles exist in `users.roles`.

```
is(roleName) {
    let roles = roleName.split('|')

    return roles.every(role => {
        return this.$page.auth.user.roles.includes(role) 
    })
}
```

Uses [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if you'd like to check if any one of the roles exist in `users.roles`.

```
is(roleName) {
    let roles = roleName.split('|')

    return roles.some(role => {
        return this.$page.auth.user.roles.includes(role) 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Array.some was exactly what I needed. Perfect.